# Powershell command for ReadinessReportCreator.exe

Tags: powershell, office365

I've got 4,000 shares to go through with the readinessreportcreator, which works when I run it locally, however I put together a command with a foreach loop to read a csv of all the DFS shares, however I need to go deeper into the folder structure, normally I would use the `-recurse` switch, but that doesn't seem to be working.

The site I got the command from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/use-the-readiness-toolkit-to-assess-application-compatibility-for-office-365-pro

The powershell I have put together is:

```
$shares = import-csv -path 'C:\temp\dfs.csv'
$shs = ($shares).share
foreach ($sh in $shs)
{

   Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Readiness Toolkit for Office\ReadinessReportCreator.exe" "$sh" Out-File "C:\temp"

write-host "share=" $sh
}
```

The command the site suggest from a command line is:

`ReadinessReportCreator.exe -p c:\officefiles\ -r -output \\server01\finance`

I was thinking if I could just use the foreach loop and change `c:\officefiles\` with the variable of the share it would run through each folder and subfolder, but it doesn't like the -p, -r or the -output. Porbably because they're not powershell cmdlets, so -p should be -path and -r should be -recurse and -output should be out-file, but onlu out-file is recognised.

Excel file si:

share
`\\vmshare\share
\\vm3share\share1
\\vm2share\share2
\\vm2share\share3`

Hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really an opinion question, not a PowerShell code issue/error one, which is what most are here to assist with. Opinions can vary widely, so, hence the push back you may get. However, with this many shares. I'd suggest you look at background jobs and parallel processing. Loping is fine, but there are considerations regarding performance, hence the sugggestion.

Comment: @postanote Thaks for the input posta, I'm a newbie when it comes to powershell so will look around for background jobs, I can leave it running, time isn't the issue, the fact someone has to site and wade through so many shares is a bit of a concern, we'd like to retain the staff and not drive them away :)

Comment: No worries. It's ok to be new, just be sure to ramp up as much as needed, like leveraging PowerShell videos on Youtube, MSDN CHannel9, MS TechCommunity, and all the other free resources, cheatsheets, out there.

Answer (score 0):

1)Info from site above:

```
ReadinessReportCreator.exe -p c:\officefiles\ -r -output \\server01\finance -silent
```

The following is an example of a command line that you can run to scan a folder, and all its subfolders, and save the results to a network share for the Finance department. **This only scans for VBA macros**.

2)Can't see structure your csv file, but i have doubt about this rows of code(not sure what in `$shs`):

```
$shares = import-csv -path 'C:\temp\dfs.csv'
$shs = ($shares).share
```

3)When you run command Start-Process you must pass parameters via key `-ArgumentList`,
`-Wait` — Wait for the process to be finished before accepting any more inputs.

```
Start-Process .\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "register --estNumber $Number --postcode `"$PostCode`" --password $Password" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

4)For more about `Start-Process` enter in cli `Get-Help Start-Process -Online`